# Trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I wonder how does a [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%282x%29+%2a+cos%5E2x) get this relation where input is a LHS and output is RHS:

$$\cos^2(x)\cos(2x) = \tfrac{1}{4}\cos(4x) + \tfrac{1}{2}\cos(2x) + \tfrac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Are you asking how to prove that equality?

Comment: Express $\cos^2(x)$ in terms of $\cos(2x), \sin(2x)$ and then use product-to-sum.

Comment: Yes. I need to know how to get RHS out of LHS. I tried to use the double angle trigonometric identity and it only got more complicated...

Comment: How Alpha gets it is an interesting question. I don't know, but it is likely not the way a human should approach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\cos^2(x)\cos(2x) &= \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x))\cos(2x)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) +\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(2x) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\cos(4x)
\end{align*}
by two applications of the double angle formula.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$cos^2x=\frac{1+cos(2x)}{2}$$
$$cos^2(2x)=?$$